# Micropython: https request blocks further requests

Tags: iot, esp32, micropython

I'm on a M5Stack atom lite running micropython, making `POST` requests to a given endpoint with json payload. The following code leads to suspicious behaviour:

```
  if (pin1.value()) == True:
    if uart1.any():
      try:
        req = urequests.request(method='POST', url='https://my-server.com/my-endpoint', json={'requestCode':'yadayada'})

        if req.status_code == 200:
            rgb.setColorAll(0x00ff00)
            rgb.setBrightness(100)
            wait_ms(1500)
            rgb.setBrightness(0)
        else:
          rgb.setColorAll(0xff0000)
          rgb.setBrightness(100)
          wait_ms(1500)
          rgb.setBrightness(0)

      except:
        pass
  wait_ms(2)
```

The first request succeeds and the correct payload is sent to the endpoint. Yet, all subsequent requests fail.

- The same holds true for `GET` requests to https endpoints.
- If I change to http, both `GET` and `POST` requests work fine, one after another.
- Defining the content type in the headers has no effect.
- Neither does closing the session right after the request (using headers).

As of request 2, to a https endpoint, I get the exception:
`OSError(-17040, 'MBEDTLS_ERR_RSA_PUBLIC_FAILED+MBEDTLS_ERR_MPI_ALLOC_FAILED')`

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong with these https-requests? Thanks in advance for any hints!

Comment: I'm not familiar with the atom lite, but it sounds like you may be running out of memory (I've worked a bunch with the esp8266, and I've basically given up on ever using ssl for exactly this reason).

Comment: Thanks @larsks for your comment. You are very right, it seems that memory limits are exceeded after the first TLS-certificate. I haven't found a way around this other than restarting the device after the request ;)

Comment: @astriffe you *might* get sufficient ram back if you `gc.collect()` in between.  But you're probably better off without https in this env, sadly.